# global costmap is not centered

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, global-costmap, frames, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running the move_base node with dynamic global_cosmap.

here is global_costmap_params.yaml file:

[image: image description]

and costmap_common_params.yaml:
[image: image description]

and this is how global costmap looks like in rviz:
[image: image description]

you see, robot position starts in the corner, not in the center of global costmap

**What can i do to make global costmap centered?**

I have mapping node which is publishing the OccupancyGrid.
I have a python script that is taking this OccupancyGrid and publishing it in map frame:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import tf_conversions

import tf2_ros
import tf2_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg
import sensor_msgs.msg
import nav_msgs.msg
from std_msgs.msg import String

def handle_map_frame(data):
  pub = rospy.Publisher("map", nav_msgs.msg.OccupancyGrid, queue_size=10)
  rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz

  data.header.frame_id = "/map"

  pub.publish(data)
  rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  rospy.init_node('map_frame_broadcaster')
  rospy.Subscriber("/occupancy", nav_msgs.msg.OccupancyGrid, handle_map_frame)
  ##rospy.Subscriber('/sensor_us', sensor_msgs.msg.Range, handle_camera_pose)
  rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333360/global-costmap-is-not-centered/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should set the parameter `rolling_window` to `true` in your `global_costmap_params.yaml`.

You can check out [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/223880/what-is-rolling-window-used-for/) answer for more information.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-09-19**:
thanks a lot! it helped

**Comment by [Buzzology](https://answers.ros.org/users/123949/buzzology/) on 2023-01-08**:
This worked for me too, thanks!